# How can I communicate with a Linux device via SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd, openssh, android

How can I communicate with a Linux computer from my Android phone with the help of SSH?

I connected Android device from Linux computer vith SSH.

How I communicate with a linux machine via SSH?

Comment: what does "I can not do this" mean? connected how?

Comment: Its mean : I installed openssh-server on my linux computer, after Iinstalled termux to my my android device after I tryed connect to ssh it does not connected. Sorry for my english

Comment: The Android device and the PC **must be** in the same *network*, once this is done you only need to install some android *apks* that allow you use *SSH* for "talk" with PC (I use one that is free: **ConnectBot**).

Comment: Yes, devices in the same network. ConnectBot did not give any output.

Comment: I'm also using ConnectBot.  Do you know on what port and IP address sshd is listening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you have ssh acess on the account you are trying to connect to. open `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and add:

```
PermitRootLogin no
AllowUsers username
```

Replace username with the user you would like to ssh into. Restart ssh with either `sudo service ssh reload` or `systemctl restart sshd`

Comment: Did not. Can a program block openssh. How can I look for it.

Comment: A firewall on your computer or network could block ssh. Make sure your firewall has rules to allow connections with port 22.

Comment: Firewall blocks